# javascript loop for mysql data

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a menu bar that is populated with user names from MYSQL. When users click on the menu button USERS, it will drop down listing all the users in the database. Essentially I'm wanting something like the following:

```
Menu1=new Array("Users","blank.htm","",2,31,133);
    Menu1_1=new Array("userone","blank.htm","",5,31,150);   
        Menu1_1_1=new Array("Message","message/php","",0,31,150);
        Menu1_1_2=new Array("Wave","wave.php","",0);
        Menu1_1_3=new Array("Block","block.php","",0);
    Menu1_2=new Array("usertwo","blank.htm","",3);
        Menu1_2_1=new Array("Message","message/php","",0,31,150);
        Menu1_2_2=new Array("Wave","wave.php","",0);
        Menu1_2_3=new Array("Block","block.php","",0);
    Menu1_3=new Array("userthree","blank.htm","",3);
        Menu1_3_1=new Array("Message","message/php","",0,31,150);
        Menu1_3_2=new Array("Wave","wave.php","",0);
        Menu1_3_3=new Array("Block","block.php","",0);
```

The Menu1_(whatever number) would be created for each in the MYSQL database. The userone,usertwo,etc would be the username from MYSQL. I would like to list all users but use a vertical scrollbar if there's more than 5 listings. The MYSQL query would vary from user to user since the end result is to only list friends of that specific user. I can do the PHP to call the MYSQL data. The issue is looping it in the JS script for each username.

Comment: The drop down menu is created in JS. The code above works as is. There are no errors. However I want to loop the Menu1_(whatever number) while populating it with data from MYSQL. Pretty sure I stated this already but you must not be clear on what I am hoping for.

Comment: You can have your PHP generate json and use xmlhttprequest in JavaScript to fetch the data. It looks like in your case you only need an array of strings containing the user names: http://php.net/json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer `I would like to list all users` you could write them into an array:

```
function iterateUsers(){        
    UserBlankPages = new Array(
        new Array("userone", "blank.htm", " ", 5, 31, 150)   
        ,new Array("usertwo", "blank.htm","",3)
        ,new Array("userthree", "blank.htm","",3)
    );

    var currentUser, userName;

    for (var i = 0; i < UserBlankPages.length; i++) {       
        currentUser = UserBlankPages[i];
        userName = currentUser[0];
        alert('userName = ' + userName);
    }               
}
```

I can not answer `but use a vertical scrollbar if there's more than 5 listings` since i do not know how your html looks like. If you create a select-list and add elements to it it creates a vertical scrollbar:

```
<select name="Users">
   <option>One</option>
   <option>Two</option>
   <option>Three</option>
</select>
```

To answer `the end result is to only list friends` and `The issue is looping it in the JS script for each username`. This is the same as above; if you create an array that contains every friend of a certain user you can loop through it like above.